# Tkinter GUI freezes often

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

Recently I created a GUI which gets an CSV file and plots the mean and std for a chosen variable at chosen location.

The GUI was working perfectly fine until a few days ago. It has started to crash (Not responding) either as soon as I load the CSV file or after i select the location variable.  Sometimes it plots the first set of data and then it stops working (i should be able to re select the data and re-plot).

However very often it works and plots the mean and std.

I have search google over and over again but couldn't find any answer to my problem.

I would be grateful if anyone can help and give a solution.

```
import matplotlib
from Tkinter import *
import csv
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,    NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import inspect, os


root=Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1500, 900, 500, 150))
root.title("Spectroscopy Library 1.0")
root.configure(bg='white')
#root.iconbitmap(iconpath)   # setting the icon 

T = Text(root, height=1, width=40,bg='white', fg='gray13',font=("Helvetica",24))
T.pack()
T.insert(END, "Tumor Average Spectra, Short Echo Time at 1.5 T")

filename = askopenfilename() 
Label(root, text="Location:",bg='white').grid(row=3, sticky=W)
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Posterior Fossa", variable=var1,bg='white').grid(row=4, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(root, text="Supratentorial", variable=var2,bg='white').grid(row=5, sticky=W)


def tumor_select():


    #----------------- calculating the file length---------------------------------
    csv_file_size = open(filename, 'rU')
    dataforsize = csv.reader(csv_file_size, delimiter=',')
    row_count = pl.sum(1 for row2 in dataforsize)

    #------------------defining matrixes-------------------------------------------

    csv_file = open(filename, 'rU')
    #    csv_file = open("/Users/Emsku/Documents/Python/modeldata5.csv", "rU")
    data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    tumor = ["" for x in range(row_count)]  # defining an empty string
    region = ["" for y in range(row_count)]  #defining an empty string
    fit = np.zeros((row_count, 456))  #defining a int array

    #     data into arrays
    f = 0
    for row in data:
        tumor[f] = row[0]
        region[f] = row[1]
        fit[f] = row[2:]
        f += 1

    #---------------- devining data into region and tumor types -------------------

    atrt = [];atrtfit =[];atrtloc =[]
    gbm = [];gbmfit = [];gbmloc = []
    gng = [];gngfit = [];gngloc = []
    dast = [];dastfit = [];dastloc = []
    aast = [];aastfit = [];aastloc = []
    carn = [];carnfit = [];carnloc = []
    cpp = [];cppfit = [];cpploc = []
    cnspri = [];cnsprifit = [];cnspriloc = []
    dnt = [];dntfit = [];dntloc = []
    acpp = [];acppfit = [];acpploc = []
    past = [];pastfit = [];pastloc = []
    pin = [];pinfit = [];pinloc = []
    cpc = [];cpcfit = [];cpcloc = []
    germ = [];germfit = [];germloc = []
    epen = [];epenfit = [];epenloc = []
    anepen = [];anepenfit = [];anepenloc = []
    med = [];medfit = [];medloc = []
    dnmed = [];dnmedfit = [];dnmedloc = []
    lmed = [];lmedfit = [];lmedloc = []
    ast = [];astfit = [];astloc = []
    sepen = [];sepenfit = [];sepenloc = []
    glicer = [];glicerfit = [];glicerloc = []
    gcast = [];gcastfit = [];gcastloc = []
    swm = [];swmfit = [];swmloc = []
    pong = [];pongfit = [];pongloc = []
    ppm = []


    for index, type in enumerate(tumor):
        if type == 'Atypical Teratoid - Rhabdoid Tumour':
            atrt.append(index)
            atrtfit.append(fit[index,])
            atrtloc.append(region[index])
        if type == 'Glioblastoma':
            gbm.append(index)
            gbmfit.append(fit[index,])
            gbmloc.append(region[index])
        if type == 'ganglioglioma':
            gng.append(index)
            gngfit.append(fit[index,])
            gngloc.append(region[index])
        if type == 'diffuse_astrocytoma':
            dast.append(index)
            dastfit.append(fit[index,])
            dastloc.append(region[index])


       # part of the code (same as above for other tumor types) not included here


    ppm = fit[0,]

     # ATRT tumor
    atrt_pf=[];atrt_sp=[]
    for index, type in enumerate(atrtloc):
        if type == 'posterior fossa':
            atrt_pf.append(atrtfit[index])
        elif type == 'Supratentorial':
            atrt_sp.append(atrtfit[index])

    if len(atrt_pf)>1:
        atrtave_pf = np.mean(atrt_pf, axis=0);atrtsd_pf = np.std(atrt_pf, axis=0)
    elif len(atrt_pf)==1:
        atrtave_pf = np.mean(atrt_pf, axis=0) ;atrtsd_pf = np.zeros((456, 1))

    if len(atrt_sp)>1:
        atrtave_sp = np.mean(atrt_sp, axis=0);atrtsd_sp = np.std(atrt_sp, axis=0)
    elif len(atrt_sp)==1:
        atrtave_sp = np.mean(atrt_sp, axis=0); atrtsd_sp = np.zeros((456, 1))

    # Glioblastoma

    gbm_pf=[]; gbm_sp=[]
    for index, type in enumerate(gbmloc):
        if type == 'posterior fossa':
            gbm_pf.append(gbmfit[index])
        elif type == 'Supratentorial':
            gbm_sp.append(gbmfit[index])

    if len(gbm_pf)>1:
        gbmave_pf = np.mean(gbm_pf, axis=0);gbmsd_pf = np.std(gbm_pf, axis=0)
    elif len(gbm_pf)==1:
        gbmave_pf = np.mean(gbm_pf, axis=0) ;gbmsd_pf = np.zeros((456, 1))

    if len(gbm_sp)>1:
        gbmave_sp = np.mean(gbm_sp, axis=0);gbmsd_sp = np.std(gbm_sp, axis=0)
    elif len(gbm_sp)==1:
        gbmave_sp = np.mean(gbm_sp, axis=0); gbmsd_sp = np.zeros((456, 1))

    # Ganglioglioma

    gng_pf=[]; gng_sp=[]
    for index, type in enumerate(gngloc):
        if type == 'posterior fossa':
            gng_pf.append(gngfit[index])
        elif type == 'Supratentorial':
            gng_sp.append(gngfit[index])

    if len(gng_pf)>1:
        gngave_pf = np.mean(gng_pf, axis=0);gngsd_pf = np.std(gng_pf, axis=0)
    elif len(gng_pf)==1:
        gngave_pf = np.mean(gng_pf, axis=0) ;gngsd_pf = np.zeros((456, 1))

    if len(gng_sp)>1:
        gngave_sp = np.mean(gng_sp, axis=0);gngsd_sp = np.std(gng_sp, axis=0)
    elif len(gng_sp)==1:
        gngave_sp = np.mean(gng_sp, axis=0); gngsd_sp = np.zeros((456, 1))


    dast_pf=[]; dast_sp=[]
    for index, type in enumerate(dastloc):
        if type == 'posterior fossa':
            dast_pf.append(dastfit[index])
        elif type == 'Supratentorial':
            dast_sp.append(dastfit[index])



    if len(dast_pf)>1:
        dastave_pf = np.mean(dast_pf, axis=0);dastsd_pf = np.std(dast_pf, axis=0)
    elif len(dast_pf)==1:
        dastave_pf = np.mean(dast_pf, axis=0) ;dastsd_pf = np.zeros((456, 1))

    if len(dast_sp)>1:
        dastave_sp = np.mean(dast_sp, axis=0);dastsd_sp = np.std(dast_sp, axis=0)
    elif len(dast_sp)==1:
        dastave_sp = np.mean(dast_sp, axis=0); dastsd_sp = np.zeros((456, 1))



       # part of the code (same as above for other tumor types) not included here


var3 = StringVar(root)
# initial value
var3.set(' Select Tumor Type ')
choices = ['Atypical Teratoid Rhabdoid Tumour', 'Anaplastic astrocytoma','Anaplastic ependymoma','Atypical Choroid Plexus Papilloma', 'Craniopharyngioma adamantinomatous', 'Choroid Plexus Carcinoma', 'Choroid plexus papilloma', 'CNS_primitive_neuroectodermal_tumour_94733', 'Diffuse astrocytoma', 'Dysembryoplastic Neuroepithelial Tumour','Desmoplastic-Nodular Medulloblastoma','Ependymoma ', 'Glioblastoma', 'Gliomatosis cerberi', 'Ganglioglioma', 'Germinoma','Large Cell Medulloblastoma','Medulloblastoma ', 'Pilomyxoid astrocytoma', 'Pinoblastoma', 'Pontine glioma', 'Pilocytic astrocytoma ', 'Schwannoma', 'Subependymoma', 'Unbiopsied Subependymal Giant Cell Astrocytoma']
option =OptionMenu(root, var3, *choices).grid(row=10, sticky=W)
button = Button(root, text="       Plot average Spectra   ", command=tumor_select,bg="alice blue").grid(row=12, sticky=W)
#button.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10)
close_button = Button(root, text="                   Quit                   ", command=root.destroy).grid(row=16, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the input file as you may be running out of memory.  You have 2 lists containing the input file, and three more lists that are just the input file split up, and then numpy arrays of some of the same data.  This code converts the csv file to an SQL database on disk, so file/memory size is not an issue (it should become obvious why this would be easier with an SQL database).  Then a common function simulates the plot, but prints instead so you will know if a) it works as you want it to and b) if the program still hangs, it is not this piece of code that is the problem.  Note that I have no idea what input data looks like so you will have to adjust where necessary.  Some tutorials http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/ and http://freshmeat.net/articles/sqlite-tutorial

```
"""obviously this is a stripped down version in the interest
   of time spent
"""

import os
import random
import sqlite3 as sqlite

def tumor_select(cur):
    """ select the specified tumors and get and print
        for each of the regions that you want
    """
    tumor_list=['Atypical Teratoid - Rhabdoid Tumour','Glioblastoma',
                  'ganglioglioma', 'diffuse_astrocytoma']
    region_list=['posterior fossa', 'Supratentorial']

    print "\n========== tumor function================="
    for tumor in tumor_list:
        ## append to list to be used in calcs instead of print
        for region in region_list:
            print "-"*70
            print "%7s  %-38s %-15s %5s" % ("rec-num", "tumor",
                  "region", "fit")
            ## using the dictionary look up method which has advantages IMHO
            cur.execute("select * from test_dbf where t_tumor=:d_tumor and t_region=:d_region",
                       {"d_tumor": tumor, "d_region": region})
            found=cur.fetchall()
            for row in found:
                print "%7d  %-38s %-15s %5s" % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])

def open_file():
    """ creates a new SQL file with the fields below and populates
        it with the csv data each time the program is run
    """
    f_name="./test_1.SQL"
    if os.path.isfile(f_name):
        os.remove(f_name)
    con = sqlite.connect(f_name)
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE test_dbf(t_rec_num int, t_tumor varchar, t_region varchar, t_fit varchar)''')

    ## add each rec to the SQL DB
    with open("./test_1.csv", "r") as fp_in:
        for rec_num, rec in enumerate(fp_in):
            fields = rec.strip().split(",")
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO test_dbf values (?,?,?,?)', tuple([rec_num]+fields))
        con.commit()
    return cur

def print_all_recs(cur):
    cur.execute("select * from test_dbf")
    recs_list=cur.fetchall()
    for rec in recs_list:
        print rec

## output some test data
tumor_list=['Atypical Teratoid - Rhabdoid Tumour','Glioblastoma',
                  'ganglioglioma', 'diffuse_astrocytoma',
                  'something else']
region_list=['posterior fossa', 'Supratentorial',
                  'something else']

with open("./test_1.csv", "w") as fp_out:
    for ctr in range(100):
        ## don't knoe what "fit" is so just use a number
        fp_out.write("%s,%s,%s%s\n" % (random.choice(tumor_list),
                     random.choice(region_list), "fit ", ctr))

cur = open_file()
print_all_recs(cur)  ## while testing
tumor_select(cur)
```